# Django: Modify model field value when form is submitted

Tags: python, django

I have a model field for each use that keeps track of their score on my website. Every time a user does some I want to add or subtract from their score.

In this particular case, I would like to change the users score when they publish a post on my site. I am able to access the user's score, but not modify it. Here is what I have so far:

```
def createPost(request):
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    current_score = user.user_score

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            user.user_score = current_score - 1
            ...
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request,'feed/userpost_form.html',{'form':form})
```

I am not getting any errors and publishing the post works fine, just not modifying the user's score. Also, I am using Django 1.11

Comment: isn't `user.save()` missing?

Comment: @andi Yeah that was it. Small oversight on my part. thank you

Comment: Be aware of race conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you were missing `user.save()`

btw another approach could be:

```
from django.db.models import F
UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(user_score=F('user_score')+1)
```

important feature of above approach in mentioned context is:

> Another useful
>   benefit of F() is that having the database - rather than Python -
>   update a field’s value avoids a race condition.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f

Comment: You could do `user.user_score = F('user_score')  - 1` and then `user.save()` (i.e. no need to filter on the user).

Comment: Not to mention that this answer has no race condition :) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f